# How to redirect to Parent Record after Creating Child Record

Tags: apex, visualforce

Thanks David for replying.
I am launching a Survey Child Record from a Student Master Record Page.
After saving the Survey Child Record I want to be redirected to Student Master Record Page.

Below is the Code:

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class StudentSurveyCtrlr {       
    public nav1__Survey__c nSurvey {get; set;}      
    public List<SelectOption> ratings {get;set;}
    string cid;       
    public StudentSurveyCtrlr() {
        nSurvey = new nav1__Survey__c ();
        ratings = new list <SelectOption> ();
        ratings.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
        ratings.add(new SelectOption('1','1'));
        ratings.add(new SelectOption('2','2'));        
    }

    public pagereference SaveSurvey() {       
        insert nSurvey;
        cid = nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__r.Id;
        system.debug('Parent Record ID' + cid);
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+ 
        nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__r.Id);
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg; 
    }
}
```

The below Code is the VF Page which will be called by a Custom button on the New Student Master Record Page.

**VF Page**

```
                                                                             <apex:page controller="StudentSurveyCtrlr" title="Survey Questionaire" label="Survey Questionaire">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Survey Questionaire"> 
  Question 1. Satisfied  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!nSurvey.Satisfaction__c}"/>  
  Question 2. Rating       
      <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!nSurvey.Rating__c}">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!ratings }"/>
    </apex:selectList> <br/>    
  Question 3. Comments  <apex:inputTextarea value="{!nSurvey.Comments__c}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Save Survey" action="{!SaveSurvey}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

On the press of the custom button, I will be redirected to VF page which will have Survey Questions and Save button. After I press Save button on the VF page, I want to be redirected to the New Student Master Record Page.

I am seeing that the Survey child record is being saved but I am not redirected to New Student Master Record page.
Can you please guide me on this?

Comment: You added new code, but I am not sure why. Are you indicating that you have a different issue, or that the answer below did not hit the mark? Can you help clarify what support you need?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you're showing here, that `System.debug()` statement should be demonstrating that `nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__r.Id` is `null`. As a result, your redirect goes nowhere and the page simply reloads.

If you are populating that lookup field somewhere else in your code, refer to it directly as `nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__c`. It's unlikely that `nav1__StudentID__r` is a non-null sObject here.

Comment: @NaveenMittapalli, if the answer worked for you, then please go ahead and accept this (you will find a tick mark besides the answer to accept it), so that this is marked as resolved and helps anyone facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

`nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__r.Id` will be `null` as it is a related field and those fields will be available only when you explicitly query on those fields. And as the value would be null, your page would not redirect.

Replace the below code

```
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+ nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__r.Id);
```

With

```
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+ nSurvey.nav1__StudentID__c);
```

as the value of the lookup field will still be an `Id` which you might be populating somewhere in your code.